# Devise: Allow only admin to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a implemented using authentication using **devise**. And it is working fine.

I have two different roles 1) Admin and 2) Normal user.

I have added admin boolean field in the users table. For admin user I am setting admin field to true.

Now I have to allow only admin users to sign in. Is there any way to achieve this.

I am using rails 5.

Comment: you just need to override devise session controller https://gist.github.com/denmarkin/955767

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use devise_custom_authenticatable gem

```
gem install devise_custom_authenticatable
```

Open Devise enabled model(app/model/user.rb) and add :custom_authenticatable method.

```
devise :custom_authenticatable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

then define check for user role

```
def valid_for_custom_authentication?(password)
 self.has_role?(:admin)
end
```

the above method will return true or false. now you can check your login process with both normal user and admin.

for more information about authentication follow this link:

Create roles: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Devise Custom Authentication:  https://github.com/AMekss/devise_custom_authenticatable

Answer (score 1):

The most valid solution for this is to define new warden strategy (it's not so easy as to make some hard code in sessions_controller, but it's a really proper way to right good and easy-maintanable code).

https://insights.kyan.com/devise-authentication-strategies-a1a6b4e2b891

So you need to add your strategy which will validate, that user is an admin.